# Reference a "String" field containing json data in ElasticSeach

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a field of type "string" in ES that actually contains JSON format data. I would like to reference the data in the json format in my index to create visualisations using Kibana. The field is of the below format.
detail "{\"schemaVersion\":\"2.0\",\"accountId\":\"xxxxxxxx\",\"region\":\"us-east-1\",\"partition\":\"aws\",\"id\":\"xxxxxaaaabbbcccccc\"}"

Comment: sorry im short in time for a real answer but what your need is the JSON Processor ( https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/json-processor.html ) and if you dont know about ingest pipeline you need to check this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html

Comment: Thanks for the response and inputs @Pierre. I will try those.